# How should I calculate world and projection matrices in this scenario?

Tags: xna, 2d, matrix, projection

I'm trying to understand transformation matrices. Suppose I use the camera from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712296/xna-2d-camera-engine-that-follows-sprite/723918#723918), this is how my view matrix would look:

```
Matrix.Identity *
Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0) *
Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
Matrix.CreateTranslation(Scale, Scale, 0) *
Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Scale, Scale, Scale));
```

How'd I calculate my World and Projection matrices then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you want to use it for 2D games (assuming from the tags), you only need a `Transform` matrix to apply to the `SpriteBatch`, you don't need `World` and `Projection` matrices.

So, when you're drawing an object that should be drawn *inside* your game world (e.g. the main player), you use the following `Begin` method from `SpriteBatch` (XNA 4.0, replace the other parameters by what you need):

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, effect, camera.Transform);
/*
Draw the world objects like walls, players, weapons, etc.
...
*/
spriteBatch.End();
```

This will apply the camera's effect to the drawing, simulating a camera within your world.

For other visual elements that are not part of the world (like the HUD with player health, etc.), you just use the regular `Begin` method (without the camera's matrix as a parameter) to draw it, because you don't really want them to move all around the screen when the camera moves, you want them to be static.

The way the camera works is that it applies a translation matrix going in the opposite direction of where you want your camera to be (it explains the negative signs in `Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0)` to simulate a camera moving inside a world. In fact, what you're really doing is that you're moving the world around so that the camera's view is represented by the game's window.

So, say you want your camera to move to the right by 20 pixels, you want to move your whole world to the left by 20 pixels to give the user the *feeling* that they moved to the right. This is achieved by applying the camera's matrix to all the world objects, to sort of move them around.

The same goes for scaling and rotation, you move the world around when you're drawing them to give a `feeling` of change.

Comment: I know, but I need to calculate those matrices anyway - for another purpose. How would I do that?

Comment: Hum, from this link: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/72388/441565.aspx it seems like you can't with SpriteBatch (and explains that SpriteBatch does the job for you). Could you give the reasons about why you'd want to do that?

Comment: What does SpriteBatch related to Matrix calculation? I just want to calculate the projection and world matrices, not use them with SpriteBatch or something.

Comment: And a simple `world = Matrix.Identity` and `projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(/*...*/)` won't do?

Comment: How to use `Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView` for the view matrix I wrote in the question?

Comment: Something like so: `Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.1f, 1000.0f)`, but I really don't see why you'd use a projection matrix along with a camera 2D though.

Answer (score 0):

The world Translation affect object in your world, so usually it will be a simple Translation. But if you want scale, rotation, ... is done this way;

```
Matrix World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-origin,0) * MatrixCreateRotationZ(angle) * Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position,0);
```

The View Matrix is the Camera matrix, i usually use:

Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) * Matrix.CreateScale(Scale) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Viewport.Center.X, Viewport.Center.Y,0);

This is the projection Matrix used by SpriteBatch [(source)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905162400/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)

```
Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, viewport.Width, viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);   

projection = halfPixelOffset * projection;
```

The final transform is: World * View * Projection.